# How to avoid select statement during save in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a composite primary key (made of 3 columns) for an entity.

Out of 2 columns from the composite key, 1 is auto increment and another is getting populated from another entity.

when I save the entity, it executes select statement and then insert statement. 
I want to ignore/avoid execution of select statement as I know that the entity are unique and simply want to insert into the table.

I read about having a field with @Version (like `@Version Long version`) in the entity however, in that case, I will have to have a column on the table as well which I don't want.

The execution of select statement taking lots of time especially when I know that the records I am inserting are unique.

[EDITED]

my entity class is:

```
@Entity
public class Table implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private TablePK id;

    private String Name;

    private String country;
}

@Embeddable
public class TablePK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Integer age;
}
```

and the log is:

```
10:39:57.650 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select 
10:39:57.684 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Done entity load
10:39:57.693 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener - Generated identifier: 
10:39:57.705 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - committing
10:39:57.706 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
10:39:57.707 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty checking collections
10:39:57.709 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
10:39:57.709 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
10:39:57.710 [main] DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
10:39:57.726 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into Table
```

Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: @NeilStockton post edited

Comment: @NeilStockton there is select statement as you can see from log. I have removed to hide the table structure. so it says like select from Table....

Comment: @NeilStockton Hi as i said i have hidden fields in select and insert log (to hide my table structure) ...

Comment: Consequently nobody can see WTF that select is for because you have hidden the meaning. Have fun debugging your problem then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entity mapping design is wrong. Why do you need a composite identifier when you already want to use an auto-incremented column?

So, just remove the `@EmbededId` use [a simple auto-incremented identifier](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/) and map the age as a basic attribute.

But there are more questionable design decisions, like:

> I read about having a field with @Version (like @Version Long version)
>   in the entity however in that case I will have to have a column in the
>   table as well which I dont want.

The reason of the `@Version` annotation is to [prevent lost updates](https://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/) in long-running transactions or weaker isolation levels. I'm not sure why do you think it has anything to do with your current problem.

> out of 3 column from composite key, 1 is auto increment and other two
>   are getting populated from another entity.

You say 3 columns, but the composite id has only 2 columns.

I suggest you read [this comprehensive JPA and Hibernate tutorial](https://vladmihalcea.com/tutorials/hibernate/) so that you understand how Hibernate works and how you should be using it.

Comment: thanks very much for your comments. I will check with Data Architect about the composite key.

Comment: removed the embaddedId and now have id as auto generated ... and I cannot select statement anymore....
thanks @Vlad..

Answer (score 1):

I completely Agree with Vlad's answer. However for you or someone else who has a scenario similar to yours and wants to avoid the initial SELECT statement, you can make your Entity implement Persistable

```
@Entity
public class Table implements Persistable<TablePK> {

  @EmbeddedId
  private TablePK id;

  private String Name;

  private String country;

  @Override
  public boolean isNew() {
    return true; // this makes every entity a new one
  }
}
```

NOTE: Use this if you can make the guarantee that your every save() will be a unique entity like the author has mentioned in the question. It will throw exceptions in case of conflicts.

Comment: This worked for me with an Oracle.  The select statement was taking a long time and my id (a long value) was generated from a "select nextval from dual" which guaranteed the value is unique.  Thanks @Austin